# Php Preg_match for beginners

Tags: php

I need some help with `preg_match()`. I have this assignment about `preg_match()` that I need to be done.

I have this string like this `"[test|test2|test3] is [test4|test5|test6] "` I need to get the string inside the `[]`,

#### Here is my attempt:

```
$str = "[test|test2|test3] is [test4|test5|test6] "; 
preg_match_all("/\[(.*)\]/", $str, $output);
print_r($output);
```

as I read the documentation, I think its right.

#### My expected output

```
test|test2|test3
```

and

```
test4|test5|test6
```

but on my `print_r()`;

#### My actual output:

```
test|test2|test3] is [test4|test5|test6
```

---

Also is it possible that I can explode the strings the way like this?

```
array(
   [0] => test|test2|test3,
   [1] => is,
   [2] => test4|test5|test6
)
```

I'm working on a function that would parse the input and output a string like this:

```
test is test4
test is test5
test is test6

test2 is test4
test2 is test5
test2 is test6

test3 is test4
test3 is test5 
test3 is test6
```

but also it should work on input that look like this

```
 the [test|test2|test3] is so [test4|test5|test6]  and [test7|test8|test9]
```

or

```
the unicorn is so [test4|test5|test6]  and [test7|test8|test9]
```

Comment: Not an answer, but really helpful tool for `regex` beginners: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Use the `/U` modifier to make `.*` non-greedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantifiers are greedy by default. Your `.` is matching as much as possible.

Two solutions:

1. Use `(.*?)` instead. This makes the quantifier un-greedy, and will match as little as possible.
2. Use `([^\]]*)`. This is preferable because it clearly defines your endpoint.

Comment: you're great.hmm. that `?` was the secret recipe

Comment: by the way `([^\]]*)` thanks about this. but it includes spaces?

Comment: @user3789894 Yes - anything at all will be matched, except that `]` that marks the end of your search.

Comment: there's a slight problem with the 2nd one :) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82aa65c8fb75319c1aa64c29dadd1818be2dfdde

Comment: @user3789894 I was only demonstrating the "inner" part. You still need the `\[` and `\]` around it. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a899ec8bfaea42b15f7b36cb401e1ea575ef3683

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [greedy and non-greedy](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_05.htm) matching. Your match is currently doing greedy matching which means that the code will put the maximum number of characters in a match.

You can state that your matching is non-greedy by use of the `?` operator in your regex.

```
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $str, $output);
#                     ^ non-greedy
```

There are a number of ways to do this - another alterative would be to capture all characters which are not a `]`:

```
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]*)\]/", $str, $output);
```

I'm not a fan of the second one because of the increased visual complexity, but as you can tell from the other answer, opinions vary!

Comment: In the time you posted to say you were going to post, I already posted :p

Comment: I prefer to give an interim answer whilst drafting a more complete answer - I don't regard it as a race

Comment: Then why post that you're about to post? ;)

Comment: I posted an incomplete answer with a statement that there was more to follow, it was not a post that I was about to post

Comment: It doesn't matter so long as you get the result you want :-) You *can* change which answer you prefer though :o)

Comment: While I agree it's not a race, you have -2 score on your post because at the time you posted an incomplete thing that can barely be called an answer.

Comment: The initial answer specifically mentioned greedy/non-greedy matching and was posted around the same time as yours. This is really a homework question and that should be a sufficient answer to assist the person to do more research.The editing notice was to inform people not to up/down vote as more info would be forthcoming. Seems some people didn't take the hint, but c'est la guerre! :-)